# Excel VBA shape color changing on criteria

Tags: vba, excel, colors, shapes

A created a simple dashboard in an excel file which display the values entered on a separate sheet. Depending on the values entered the color of the shape (square) is changing once the macro is activated.

I am new in excel VBA and I managed to make it work but my code is really long for what it does and I believe it could be simplified. See the example below:

```
Sub ScoreCard_Icon()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim ShapeName As String
Dim SHP As Shape

WebVisits = "AS_1"
BounceRate = "AS_2"
SEOVisits = "AS_3"
PPCImpressionsShare = "AS_4"
MediaImpression = "AS_5"
FacebookReach = "AS_6"
YoutubeViews = "AS_7"
RndR = "AS_8"
EShare = "AS_9"
ENOS = "AS_10"
EComSndS = "AS_11"
CARSScore = "AS_12"

Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N53")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(WebVisits)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If

Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N54")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(BounceRate)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If


Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N55")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(SEOVisits)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If



Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N56")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(PPCImpressionsShare)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If



Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N57")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(MediaImpression)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If



Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N58")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(FacebookReach)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If



Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N59")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(YoutubeViews)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If



Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N60")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(RndR)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If



Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N61")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(EShare)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If



Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N62")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(ENOS)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If



Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N63")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(EComSndS)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If



Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test").Range("N64")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(CARSScore)

If Rng.Value = "0" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
End If

If Rng.Value = "1" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
End If

If Rng.Value = "2" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
End If

If Rng.Value = "3" Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
End If


End Sub
```

The problem is that I have 10 different sheet (reflecting values for different regions) build the same way and therefore 10 times the code you can see above but with different values. It is a real pain in the ass whenever I have to modify it or to add new regions.

Comment: I don't see a question, which part is not working?

Comment: If it works and you're looking for improvement, try codereview.stackexchange instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. As the values and corresponding colors are all the same you could create another sub to do this color change for each shape. You can then use `call` to do this action again and again with different variables or objects such as your shapes.
2. Multiple sequential `If` statements can be made cleaner by using `Else If`
3. Using `With` statements can reduce replication.
4. Be careful with your data types, in your code you have used `If Rng.Value = "1"`. By enclosing the number 1 in speech marks will be comparing it as a string against the value of your Rng cell. Doesn't seem like you have run into a problem here but its good practice to be explicit with your types.

Put this all together and your looking at something like this:

```
Sub ScoreCard_Icon()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ShapeName As String
    Dim SHP As Shape

    WebVisits = "AS_1"
    BounceRate = "AS_2"
    SEOVisits = "AS_3"
    PPCImpressionsShare = "AS_4"
    MediaImpression = "AS_5"
    FacebookReach = "AS_6"
    YoutubeViews = "AS_7"
    RndR = "AS_8"
    EShare = "AS_9"
    ENOS = "AS_10"
    EComSndS = "AS_11"
    CARSScore = "AS_12"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rectangle test")
        Call changeColor(.Range("N53").Value, .Shapes(WebVisits))
        Call changeColor(.Range("N54").Value, .Shapes(BounceRate))
        Call changeColor(.Range("N55").Value, .Shapes(SEOVisits))
        'etc...
    End With

End Sub


Sub changeColor(rngVal As Integer, SHP As Shape)
    With SHP
        If rngVal = 0 Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
        ElseIf rngVal = 1 Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
        ElseIf rngVal = 2 Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
        ElseIf rngVal = 3 Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a small sub like:

```
Sub Kolor(R As Range, s As Shape)
    Dim v As String
    v = R.Value
    With s.Fill.ForeColor
        If v = "0" Then
            .RGB = RGB(246, 0, 0)
        End If

        If v = "1" Then
            .RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)
        End If

        If v = "2" Then
            .RGB = RGB(223, 223, 19)
        End If

        If v = "3" Then
            .RGB = RGB(102, 255, 51)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

and then from `ScoreCard_Icon()`
call it like:

```
Call Kolor(Rng, SHP)
```

to replace the repeated code.

The next step might be to place the ranges and Shapes in arrays and use a loop.